# How do I get the real Webservice response, instead of 403 error?

Tags: java, jax-ws, http-status-code-403

I have been having some trouble getting the real message from a webservice.

The access used to work fine, but when I tried to test it again after sometime, AXIS 2 returned me a 403 HTTP Error.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden
```

I got to thinking what it might be, so I tried to access it through SOAP UI, and it showed me that my certificate expired.

Here's the message I got with SoapUI

```
The page requires a valid SSL client certificate
Your client certificate has expired or is not yet valid. A Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate is used for identifying you as a valid user of the resource.
```

There's more to the message, I just cut it short to keep the post as small as possible.

OK, no problem there yet, I just need to find a way to inform the user that his certificate may have expired (or any other error has happened), instead of only showing him a 403 Error.

I tried to access it with JAX-WS, and I got the same message, all I get is that, I tried looking into the exception, see if there were any hidden information there, but no luck. What I get is this:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on what I can do to get the real message? Here's the code I'm using to access it

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "myCertificatePath");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "myCertificatePassword");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacertsFilePath");

        NfeRecepcao2 nfe = new NfeRecepcao2();

        NfeDadosMsg dados = new NfeDadosMsg();
        dados.getContent().add(getFileContent("C:\\teste.xml"));

        NfeCabecMsg cabec = new NfeCabecMsg();
        cabec.setCUF("35");
        cabec.setVersaoDados("2.00");
        Holder<NfeCabecMsg> header = new Holder<NfeCabecMsg>(cabec);
        NfeRecepcao2Soap12 proxy = nfe.getNfeRecepcao2Soap12();
        NfeRecepcaoLote2Result result = proxy.nfeRecepcaoLote2(dados, header);
        for (Object o : result.getContent()){
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*getFileContent* only opens a file and generates a String from it's content.

Any pointers here would be of great assistance. Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way to see what responses you're getting is to log the soap request and response your client is sending and receiving.

If you're using JAX-WS, then

```
System.setProperty("Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", true);
```

If you're using JAX-WS RI client, then

```
System.setProperty("Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", true);
```

JAX-WS RI library got included as standard with the JDK (this was with Java 6) then Sun had to rename the property name to include 'internal'. So if you are using JAX-WS RI as it comes with the JDK then you must be sure to add the internal to the property name.